# What does "<<" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What does the `<<` mean in this line of PHP?

```
$count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;
```

Comment: Hint: The same as in a lot of other languages ;)

Comment: 6 similar answers within a minute. wow! :)

Comment: and yet nobody made a [picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007526/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-c/2007563#2007563) :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the [shift left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) operator.

so in your example you are shifting left the value 1 , $count_log2 times to the left.
so the value is 2^count_log2.

1 in 8 bit binary is 00000001
so if $count_log2 = 4, we need to get 2^4 = 16.

shifting left means moving the 1 left 4 times (since $count_log2 = 4).
lets do the steps.

1. 00000010  (2 in decimal)
2. 00000100  (4 in decimal)
3. 00001000  (8 in decimal)
4. 00010000  (16 in decimal)

so we got 2^4.

a common reason for using shift operation is that it takes less time for the processor to do a shift operation than using multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Left Bitshift, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 1):

It is a left bitshift operator. See the [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) page of the PHP manual.

To quote the manual:

> `$a << $b` - Shift left - Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

In this specific case, `$count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1` is the same as setting `$count` to `pow(2, $count_log2) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

`<<` and `>>` are the so-called bitshift operator.

`x << n` shifts the bits in the integer `x` `n` places to the left, effectively multiplying `x` with 2 to the power of `n`.

Similarly `x >> n` shifts to the left, dividing `x` by 2 to the power of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

The << and >> are called [Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php), they shift left and right respectively by a certain number of bits.

In your example:
1 << $count_log2 will shift the number 1 left by the value of $count_log2.  This is easier to see in binary where the number 1 represented as an 8-bit number would be:

```
1 - 0000 0001
```

If you shift this number left by 3 (1 << 3) you would get 8:

```
8 - 0000 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift left or shift right. See the manual on [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 0):

Its a bitwise operator for shifting bits to the left, this is not just php but many languages use this for if binary manipulation

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 0):

<< is shift left operator in PHP

$a << $b means shift the bits of $a  $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

Answer (score 0):

'>>' and '<<' are bitwise operators.
'>>' shifts to the right, and '<<' shifts to the left.

Think of it like this, in binary 25 is 00011001.
if you performed a shift left on 25, you'd have 00110010, which is 50.

If you performed a shift right on 50, you'd have 25.